# How to store recursive results while backtracking?

Tags: python, recursion, backtracking

I'm currently learning about permutation generation via recursion.

The following code I found works great for printing the permutations, but I can't seem to store the values: all values in the stack are lost upon going a level up.

```
def permute_util(str, count, result, level):

    if level == len(result):
        print(result)
        return

    for i in range(len(str)):
        if count[i] == 0:
            continue;
        result[level] = str[i]
        count[i] -= 1
        permute_util(str, count, result, level + 1)
        count[i] += 1

permute_util(list("ABC"), [2,1,1], [None]*len("AABC"), 0)
```

---

Results:

```
['A', 'A', 'B', 'C']
['A', 'A', 'C', 'B']
['A', 'B', 'A', 'C']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'A']
['A', 'C', 'A', 'B']
['A', 'C', 'B', 'A']
['B', 'A', 'A', 'C']
['B', 'A', 'C', 'A']
['B', 'C', 'A', 'A']
['C', 'A', 'A', 'B']
['C', 'A', 'B', 'A']
['C', 'B', 'A', 'A']
```

---

I've tried adding result to a global list in the base case, but only the latest level will get store while all other previous values will get overwritten, like so

```
 def permute_util(str, count, result, level):
    global glob 
    if level == len(result):
        **glob += [result]**
        return

    for i in range(len(str)):
        if count[i] == 0:
            continue;
        result[level] = str[i]
        count[i] -= 1
        permute_util(str, count, result, level + 1)
        count[i] += 1

permute_util(list("ABC"), [2,1,1], [None]*len("AABC"), 0)

['C', 'B', 'A', 'A']
['C', 'B', 'A', 'A']
['C', 'B', 'A', 'A']
['C', 'B', 'A', 'A']
['C', 'B', 'A', 'A']
['C', 'B', 'A', 'A']
['C', 'B', 'A', 'A']
['C', 'B', 'A', 'A']
['C', 'B', 'A', 'A']
['C', 'B', 'A', 'A']
['C', 'B', 'A', 'A']
['C', 'B', 'A', 'A']
['C', 'B', 'A', 'A']
```

Also tried this to the same effect:

```
 def permute_util(str, count, result, level, lists):
    global glob 
    if level == len(result):
        return [result]


    for i in range(len(str)):
        if count[i] == 0:
            continue;
        result[level] = str[i]
        count[i] -= 1
        foo = permute_util(str, count, result, level + 1, lists)
        lists = lists + foo
        count[i] += 1

   lists = []
   permute_util(list("ABC"), [2,1,1], [None]*len("AABC"), 0, lists)
```

What would be the best approach to store all "result" in the base case in a list and return it on completion?

Comment: Show us how you tried adding the result to a global list. It's likely that you did something wrong, but that's close to working, and we can show you how to fix it—but if we can't see it, nobody can fix it for you.

Comment: Meanwhile, even better than a global: either pass down another `results` list (that starts off with `[]`, but you `results.append(result)` repeatedly), or `return` the result instead of just `print`ing it and collect them on the way back up.

Comment: I tried that. Append will not work either, previous append gets overwritten when the stack pops

Comment: Well, if it's any help, one workaround that I found is to use `glob.append(''.join(result))`

Comment: Thank you, it seems the issue was that only pointers to object was appended and not the actual value itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python appends the pointer to the list rather than the actual list. Thus, what you have is a lot of pointers pointing to the final state of result hence the duplicate values. Try creating the copy every time you are appending, like the following:

```
final_ans = []
def permute_util(str, count, result, level):

    if level == len(result):
        final_ans.append(result[:])    # if you don't explicitly want list, try final_ans.append(''.join(result))
        return

    for i in range(len(str)):
        if count[i] == 0:
            continue;
        result[level] = str[i]
        count[i] -= 1
        permute_util(str, count, result, level + 1)
        count[i] += 1

permute_util(list("ABC"), [2,1,1], [None]*len("AABC"), 0)
for ans in final_ans:
    print(ans)
```

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick! I did not expect pointer like behavior at all

Answer (score 1):

As your recursion progresses, you keep mutating the result over and over again.
you could do something like this:

```
def permute_util(string, count, result, level):

    if level == len(result):
        print(result)
        res.append(tuple(result))   # stores current result as a copy in an immutable tuple
        return

    for i in range(len(string)):
        if count[i] == 0:
            continue;
        result[level] = string[i]
        count[i] -= 1
        permute_util(string, count, result, level + 1)
        count[i] += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':

    res = []

    permute_util(list("ABC"), [2, 1, 1], [None]*len("AABC"), 0)
    print(res)
```